# iOS Share Extension for apps in AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I am bulding app in Swift that has share extension as a part of the functionality. I added this extension as `Target` to my app and set the `NSExtensionActivationRule`.

My share extension is visible in Safari and other places but I cannot get it to show in AppStore. I have all posible activations rules active.

Since I can share app details from AppStore to Outlook, Skype, WhatsApp, I am assuming it is possible.

Also I tried to make this as an Action Extension but had similar problems (among the actions in AppStore there is only Copy Link and Run Worfklow (both from Apple).

How can I set my extension activation rules to use it in AppStore?

My current configuration in Info.plist is below:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```